# Query from Parse.com to UICollectionView

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to Query image with text from Parse.com to my UICollectionView. This is my code:

```
func QueryFromParse(){
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        let text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        let username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        let time = oneobject.createdAt!

                        let placeholder = UIImage(named: "Placeholder")! // Put some placeholder image here till the other image downloads.
                        var OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time, image: placeholder)
                        self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
                        let userImageFile = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                if let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                                    OneBigObject.image = newImage
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Parse.com "Posts":
[image]

```
struct Details {
    var username:String!
    var text:String!
    var CreatedAt:NSDate!
    var image:UIImage!
    init(username:String,text:String,CreatedAt:NSDate,image:UIImage){

        self.username = username
        self.text = text
        self.CreatedAt = CreatedAt
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

The images does only shows the "Placeholder" image, and not the image from Parse.com, but the image text and time is correct... Any suggestions?

Comment: can you put the code of Details class

Comment: @Lamar - Added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are into the right track, however you should only fill the **imageView.image** with the placeholder only if the user's image is nil.

Therefore In the **getDataInBackgroundWithBlock** you will check if you have the image, if **yes**

> -add the username
>
> -add the imageText
>
> -add the image
>
> -add the time it was created at
>
> -**Then insert all the information into the array**   -**Then reload
>   the CollectionView**

***However if the user'image is nil***

> -add the username
>
> -add the imageText
>
> -add the **placeholder**
>
> -add the time it was created at
>
> -**Then insert all the information into the array**   -**Then reload
>   the CollectionView**

Comment: Can you present a code for this please? Would be very helpful.